# Can't connect to postgre via public IP

Tags: postgresql, port, router, lan, wan

I can't connect to Postgre via a public IP. Things i have already tried:

Enabled DMZ to open port 5432 (verified it is open at https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/);

Changed listen_addresses to * in postgresql.conf;

Added this line to pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             clientpublicip/32       trust
```

Tried accessing it from another network with a different public IP.

The error i get is in psql command line:

Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I'm on Windows and already have disabled the firewall

What i want to do:

```
psql -U postgres -h mypublicip
```

or

```
psql -U postgres -h mydns
```

Any advice?

Comment: `-h` would be the host name or address of the server the PostgreSQL instance is running on. Are you sure you are using that? Also, you have an IP address listed in your question - I would recommend you edit that out.

Comment: My PC is running Postgre so i'm using its public IP to try to connect to it. I'm now thinking this is something related to port redirection...

Comment: wait, what os are you on? have you put postgre's port as allowed on the firewall? firewall is the cause connection refused in most cases.

Comment: I'm on Windows and i have disabled my firewall

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? If you are connecting from localhost, you dont need the changes you made. In fact, you have exposed you database to a huge security risk.

Comment: I want to connect from a PC where I work to a remote database inside my PC at home. I wanted to call psql passing the public IP as the host parameter but it seems I am missing something